# Apache/WordPress Cache Not Refreshing

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, caching, refresh

So I was trying out a caching plugin on my WP site. I had installed it after my home page never changed (forever static). Uninstalled the plugin, tried moving the WP files to another sub-domain, and my frontpage still was static. Even on another sub-domain. This only had happened when I changed some .htaccess settings for it, but I had already reverted these.

I've tried emptying my local cache, different computers, etc. Page is still static. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: :/ does no one have any idea? Still static..

Comment: No downvotes, comments, nothing?

Comment: I would like to mention, it onl happens on MY IP. Other IPs, works fine.